# How to insert same data (or copy) in a same table for different record in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `Records` which have data as following-

```
Section_one | section_two | values       | cDate

name_Fit    | hellp0      | present      | 2014-08-23
name_Fit    | onew        | parcel       | 2014-08-21
name_Fit    | twow        | new thing    | 2014-07-04
```

Now I am trying to insert a new data called `name_Fit_one` w.r.t to column `section_one` which should have similar data (w.r.t column `section_two` and `values`) corresponding to it.

I tried to write the sql to do that but I am getting error on postgres. Can anyone please correct me what am I doing wrong?

```
Insert into records(section_one,section_two,values) Values ('name_Fit_one', select section_two,values from records where section_one='name_Fit');
```

**Expected Results**

```
Section_one | section_two | values       | cDate

name_Fit    | hellp0      | present      | 2014-08-23
name_Fit    | onew        | parcel       | 2014-08-21
name_Fit    | twow        | new thing    | 2014-07-04
name_Fit_one| hellp0      | present      | 2014-08-29
name_Fit_one| onew        | parcel       | 2014-08-29
name_Fit_one| twow        | new thing    | 2014-08-29
```

Need to write single query that would copy content of one record to another record?

Below is the sql fiddle for it-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9de58/1

Comment: your tag says postgresql but your sqlfiddle is mysql. What database are you really using? Also your data shows a column "values" but your fiddle shows "value", which is correct? Also is cdate a timestamp field (as in your fiddle) or a date field (as in your data above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using postgresql you should be able to use:

```
Insert into records
  select 'name_Fit_one', section_two, values, '2014-08-29'
    from records
   where section_one = 'name_Fit';
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fbbed/1/0

Note that I renamed some of your columns as it was unclear whether your example above or your sqlfiddle contained your actual data and column names (they differ).

You can replace the literal '2014-08-29' with CURRENT_DATE if you want it to be the date in which you run the insert.

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert into records (section_one,section_two, "values") 
select 'name_Fit_one', section_two, "values" 
from records 
where section_one='name_Fit';
```

Note that `values` is a reserved word and thus needs to be quoted.